# UIAlertView and releasing object after showing it

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I am reviewing some source code and noticed this method below.  It isn't releasing the `message` after allocating it.  Shouldn't there be a `[message release];` after the show?

```
- (void)service:(TestService*)service didFailWithError:(NSObject *)error
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Service Error"
                                                message:errorMsg
                                                delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [message show];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If ARC wasn't enabled, then yes, release should have been called after `show`.